# No funciona el evento click de una tabla dinamica creada desde ajax

Tags: jquery

Esta funcion me crea una tabla segun los datos:

```
function createTableByForLoop(data)
{
  var eTable="<table id='tabla_productos' class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th>Alimento ID</th><th>Alimento nombre</th><th>Alimento cantidad</th><th>Tipo alimento id</th><th>Tipo alimento nombre</th><th>Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
  {
    eTable += "<tr>";
        eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['alimento_id']+"</td>";
        eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['alimento_nombre']+"</td>";
        //----------------
        //eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['alimento_cantidad']+"</td>";
        eTable += "<td><select class='custom-select' value='1' id='cantidad_ID' style='width:80px;'><option selected>"+data[i]['alimento_cantidad']+"</option><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>+10</option></select> </td>";
        //--
        eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['tipo_alimento_id']+"</td>";;
        eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['tipo_alimento_nombre']+"</td>";;
    eTable += "</tr>";
  }
  eTable +="</tbody></table>";
  $('#resultado').html(eTable);
}
```

Luego de ejecutarla (la tabla  se deisplayea perfectamente ), hago lo siguiente :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

            $("#tabla_productos thead").on('click', function(event) {
                alert("click!");
                /* Act on the event */
            });
    });
```

Entonces se supone que cuando clicke en la cabecera de la tabla debe salir un alert que siga **click!**, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en que el elemento al que le has atachado el evento `onclick` es un elemento que cuando carga el **DOM** (que es cuando se lo atachas) no existe todavía. Una manera de solucionarlo sería atacharle el evento al `<body>` de esta manera:

```
$('body').on('click', '#tabla_productos thead', function() {
    alert("click!");
});
```

La solución parte de uno de los parámetros opcionales que se le puede pasar a la función `on()`:

> **selector**
>
> Tipo: String
>
> Una cadena de selección para filtrar los
>   descendientes de los elementos seleccionados que desencadenan el
>   evento. Si el selector es nulo u omitido, el evento siempre se activa
>   cuando llega al elemento seleccionado.

De esta manera, aunque el evento lo tenga el elemento `<body>` lo que lo va a disparar es hacerle `click`al elemento `<tbody>` que tenga como padre un elemento `#tabla_productos` y provocará que no importe en qué momento se inserte el elemento en el **DOM**, que disparará igualmente el evento.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('body').on('click', '#miTabla thead', function() {
    alert('¡Se pincha!');
  });
  
  var html = '<thead><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td></tr></tbody>';

  $('#miTabla').html(html);
});
```

```css
thead {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="miTabla" style="width:100%">
  
  </table>
</body>
```